# Возможно ли использовать вот так оператор if

Tags: php

```
 private function getRoute()
{
   if (empty($_GET['route']))
   {
       $route = 'index';
   }
     else{
        $route = $_GET['route'];                
        $rt=explode('/', $route);
        $route=$rt[(count($rt)-1)]; 
        if($rt[(count($rt)-2)]=="product"){         
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE url like '$route'";
             $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());

             if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
             {
                 $_REQUEST['id']=$row->id;
                 $route="product";
             }

        }
     }

    if (empty($_GET['route']))
   {
       $route = 'index';
   }
   else{
        $route = $_GET['route'];                
        $rt=explode('/', $route);
        $route=$rt[(count($rt)-1)]; 
        if($rt[(count($rt)-2)]=="image"){           
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE url like '$route'";
             $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());

             if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
             {
                 $_REQUEST['id']=$row->id;
                 $route="image";
             }

        }
   }



    return $route;
}
```

здесь у меня идут 2 оператора if в одной функции, если меняю второй на `if else`, то у меня выдает ошибку синтаксиса. Правильно ли я все написал или можно как то изменить,чтобы все нормально  работало и было правильно?

Comment: Может вам нужно elseif (else if)?

Comment: @artes Где здесь "второй if", который вы хотите заменить на if-else, и что за ошибку выдает компилятор?

Comment: `if (empty($_GET['route']))
   {
       $route = 'index';
   }`
вот он повторяется 2 раза

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting `
 а ошибка вот такая

Comment: @artes Я не знаю, почему он у вас повторяется, но тем не менее  как вы его хотите записать?:)

Comment: @artes Все правильно. У вас будет ошибка, так как уже имеется перед ним else.

Comment: если пишу `elseif`, то ошибка уже вот такая `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF`,но сути не меняет

Comment: мне нужно,чтобы после  `if` выполнялись оба `else`. а если я напишу один `if`, а после него ` else` и  `elseif` , то так будет правильно или можно иначе.

Comment: можно было бы,но у меня уже к разным бд подключение идет. к product и image, а здесь только к одному,если я правильно понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private function getRoute()
{
   if (empty($_GET['route'])){
       $route = 'index';
   }
   else{
        $route = $_GET['route'];                
        $rt=explode('/', $route);
        $route=$rt[(count($rt)-1)]; 
        if($rt[(count($rt)-2)]=="product"){         
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE url like '$route'";
             $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());

             if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
             {
                 $_REQUEST['id']=$row->id;
                 $route="product";
             }
        }

        if($rt[(count($rt)-2)]=="image"){           
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE url like '$route'";
             $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());

             if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
             {
                 $_REQUEST['id']=$row->id;
                 $route="image";
             }
        }
    }
    return $route;
}
```

Comment: Nastya, спасибо огромное. Это помогло.